# "keyerror: month" when removing column from csv

Tags: python, csv

I'm looking to remove the "month" column from this csv file using python and i get an error saying "keyerror: month"

```
import csv

filename = "onedirectionsearch.csv"
with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile: 
    csvreader = csv.DictReader(csvfile) #creating a reader using DictReader
    
    with open("testwriter.csv", "w") as newfile:
        fieldnames = ["month", "harry styles: (Worldwide)", "zayn malik: (Worldwide)", "niall Horan: (Worldwide)", "liam payne: (Worldwide)", "louis tomlinson: (Worldwide)", "one direction: (Worldwide)"]
        #the above line is delcaring all the headings of the csv file
        csvwriter = csv.DictWriter(newfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        #csvwriter.writeheader()
    
    
        for line in csvreader:
            del line["month"]
            csvwriter.writerow(line)
```

Comment: A `print(list(line.keys()))` in the right place will show you the keys the DictReader has used.

Comment: Can you show `onedirectionsearch.csv` sample content?

Answer (score 1):

Well, since it's only the first element that you don't want you could do:

**Old table**

```
fieldnames = ["month", "harry styles: (Worldwide)", "zayn malik: (Worldwide)", "niall Horan: (Worldwide)", "liam payne: (Worldwide)", "louis tomlinson: (Worldwide)", "one direction: (Worldwide)"]


fieldnames

['month',
 'harry styles: (Worldwide)',
 'zayn malik: (Worldwide)',
 'niall Horan: (Worldwide)',
 'liam payne: (Worldwide)',
 'louis tomlinson: (Worldwide)',
 'one direction: (Worldwide)']
```

**New table**

```
fieldnames.pop(0)

fieldnames

['harry styles: (Worldwide)',
 'zayn malik: (Worldwide)',
 'niall Horan: (Worldwide)',
 'liam payne: (Worldwide)',
 'louis tomlinson: (Worldwide)',
 'one direction: (Worldwide)']
```